# fb:registration - can't run and store extra data like $user_ip

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

I try to store the same data using the Facebook Registration plugin. So far it works very well. Here is the code I use:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script src="https://connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js"></script>
    <script>
        FB.init({
            appId:'23xxxxxxxxxx48',
            cookie:true,
            status:true,
            xfbml:true
        });
    </script>

    <fb:registration
       fields="[{'name':'name'}, {'name':'email'}, {'name':'location'}, {'name':'birthday'}, {'name':'agb', 'description':'Ich bin mit den AGB´s einverstanden', 'type':'checkbox'}]"
                redirect-uri="https://www.myserver.de/fbapp2-0/fbregconfirm.php"
                width="510">
    </fb:registration>
</div>
```

and here is the `fbregconfirm.php`:

```
define('FACEBOOK_APP_ID', '23xxxxxxx48');
define('FACEBOOK_SECRET', 'f6xxxxxxxf0');

function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
    list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);

    // Decode the data
    $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
    $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

    if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
        error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
        return null;
    }

    // Check signature
    $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
    if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
        error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
        return null;
    }
    return $data;
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
    return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}

if ($_REQUEST) {
    $response = parse_signed_request($_REQUEST['signed_request'],
                                     FACEBOOK_SECRET);
    $name =$response["registration"]["name"];
    $name_arr = explode(' ',$name,2); $vname = $name_arr[0]; $zname = isset($name_arr[1])?$name_arr[1]:'';
    $email =$response["registration"]["email"];
    $ort = $response["registration"]["location"]["name"];
    $ort_arr = explode(' ',$ort,2); $ort1 = $ort_arr[0]; $ort2 = isset($ort_arr[1])?$ort_arr[1]:'';
    $anrede = $response["registration"]["gender"];
    $geburtstag = $response["registration"]["birthday"];
}

// Connecting to database
mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());

// Inserting into users table
$vname = mysql_real_escape_string($vname);
$zname = mysql_real_escape_string($zname);
$ort1 = mysql_real_escape_string($ort1);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$user_fbid = mysql_real_escape_string($user_fbid);
$geburtstag = date("Y-m-d" , strtotime($geburtstag));

$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO member (mem_id, anrede, vname, zname, plz, ort, land_id, email, userpass, regdatum, regip, lastlogin, agbok, free, memkey, letter, nameindex, memoptionen, memstatus, regok, geburtstag, notizen, partner_id, fbuid)
                      VALUES     (NULL, '".$anrede."', '".$vname."', '".$zname."', '".$plz."', '".$ort1."', '"$ort2"', '".$email."',  MD5('".$pwrand."'),NOW(),'".$user_ip."', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '1','1', '','".$letter."','".$nameindex."','', '2', '1','".$geburtstag."', '".$formkeys['datenfeld']."', '1', '".$response["user_id"]."')")};
```

But now I want to store same extra data for example

```
$user_ip  = get_uip();
$pwrand   = multirandom(1, 8, 14, '');
```

Every time I try to include this or similar code it shows me an http500 error. How can I include these extra data and store them in MySQL?

Comment: Check your Apache error log and see what it says.

Comment: It's a plugin to _what_ system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is very simple. I forgot including another PHP file where I manage all global information with definition of several other variables like `$user_ip` and `$pwrand`.

Comment: When answering your own question, please give more information, such as the code that helped you fix your problem. For example, explain which file and variables. This will help others who have a similar issue. Thanks!